# Creating a virtual drive in windows server that ,maps to a CentOS server folder in same network

Tags: linux, windows, virtualization, hard-drive

Is it possible to creating a virtual drive (E.g. drive D) in windows server that ,maps to a CentOS (linux based) server folder in same network?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, you can try to use [Starwind vSAN](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san-free) (free software) to share entire physical drive/virtual drive (SCSI disk) using the iSCSI protocol to the CentOS machine with iscsid. Or create a simple NFS share on Windows Server and mount it on CentOS machine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The easies way: Set up samba on the CentOS machine, configure a share (and appropiate security settings) and map that share on the windows machine (`net use X: \\<CentOSMachine>\<sharename>`). It is not possible to share a physical drive.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, I found the other solution better.